# The expected value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r}}$ where $r$ is Pearson correlation

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, expected-value, unbiased-estimator

I am looking to unbias the sample statistic $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r}}$ where $r$ is a Pearson correlation. The population is assumued binormal with equal variance $\sigma$ and with true correlation $\rho$.

We know the density PDF of $r$,
$$f(r;n,\rho) =\frac{(n-2) \left(1-\rho ^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \left(1-r^2\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-2} \Gamma (n-1) (1-\rho  r)^{\frac{3}{2}-n} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};n-\frac{1}{2};\frac{r \rho }{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
where $n$ is the sample size.

With a transformation on $r$, it is possible to derive the density of $1/\sqrt{1-r}$, namely
$$h(y; n, \rho) = -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} (n-2) y^3 \left(1-\rho ^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \left(\frac{2 y^2-1}{y^4}\right)^{n/2} \Gamma (n-1) \left((\rho
   -1) y^2-\rho \right) \left(\rho  \left(\frac{1}{y^2}-1\right)+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-n} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};n-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{\rho }{y^2}+\rho +1\right)\right)}{\left(1-2 y^2\right)^2 \Gamma
   \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
(the numerator is two-lines long) where $y$ is a variate going from $1/\sqrt{2}$ to $\infty$ (in which $y = 1/\sqrt{1-r}$)).

I am unable however to get the expected value of this function. Also, the purpose is to get an unbiasing function, so is the expected value going to be independent from the true $\rho$?